# Is there a way to use the CMD button in the right side as a different button?

Tags: macos, keyboard

You know in the keyboard we have 2 CMD buttons, one on the left side of the SPACE and on on the right side.

My question is, can I make OSX treat the one on the right side as a completely different button? So I can assign different actions to shortcuts such as CMD(left) + K and CMD(right) + K.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use KeyRemap4MacBook (Karabiner) to remap your keyboard.

**Karabiner**

```
A powerful and stable keyboard customizer for OS X.

 - You can easily customize from prepared settings.
 - You can also add your own settings by XML.
```

https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/